# What is the internal implementation of lists?

Tags: r, list

I am curious how an object of type `list` is implemented. Is it

1. a dynamic vector that will automatically increase its size when it is full.
2. a linked list where appending an item is `O(1)`, but accessing an item is `O(n)`.
3. a tree structure with `O(log(n))` item access.
4. a hashtable with `O(1)` item access.

I am curious because lists can have key-value pairs that make them look like hash tables, but the elements are in order, which looks like a vector.

**Edit**: because `length(list(runif(1e4)))` is 1, so when append element to a list, it looks like that it copy the whole list every time, that makes it very slow:

But the access speed is much slower than a vector:

```
z1 <- runif(1e4)
system.time({
  for(i in 1:10000) z1[[1 + i]] <- 1
})
```

outputs:

```
user  system elapsed 
0.060   0.000   0.062
```

but:

```
z1 <- list(runif(1e4))
system.time({
  for(i in 1:10000) z1[[1 + i]] <- 1
})
```

outputs:

```
user  system elapsed 
1.31    0.00    1.31
```

init a list with 10000 elements:

```
z1 <- as.list(runif(1e4))
system.time({
  for(i in 1:10000) z1[[1 + i]] <- 1
})
```

outputs:

```
user  system elapsed 
0.060   0.000   0.065
```

For the key & value access:

```
z1 <- list()
for(i in 1:10000){key <- as.character(i); z1[[key]] <- i} 
system.time({
  for(i in 1:10000) x <- z1[["1"]]
})
system.time({
  for(i in 1:10000) x <- z1[["10000"]]
})
```

The output is:

```
user  system elapsed 
0.01    0.00    0.01 
user  system elapsed 
1.78    0.00    1.78
```

It's not an `O(1)` access, so it's not a hash table. My conclusion is that it's not a dynamic array since appending items will cause memory accesses every time; it's not a hashtable since access by key is not `O(1)`.

Comment: I would have voted you twice if you had put your analysis in an answer (where it should be IMHO.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lists are essentially just arrays of R objects (`SEXP`). Resizing causes copies of the whole data and name lookup is linear.

Alternatively, you can use environments, which use hash tables internally.

Comment: So if a `list` is an array of `SEXP`s, why is lookup linear and not constant? Or is *name* lookup linear and *indexed* lookup constant?

Comment: I did write name lookup.

Comment: I can't find a case of performance drop for growing a list in R vs lapply? Example code system.time({ l = list(); for(i in 1:50000) l[[i]] = letters}) Is it for most practical concerns not a problem? Instead of letters it could also be some random numbers, generated with rnorm.