# How to force dispatch to an internal generic in R?

Tags: r

I have a class 'myClass' in R that is essentially a list.  It has an assignment operator which is going to do some things and then should assign the value using the regular list assignment operator

```
`$<-.myClass`<-function(x,i,value){
   # do some pre-processing  stuff

   # make the assignment using the default list assignment
   x[[i]]<-value
   x
 }
```

But I can't actually use `x[[i]]<-value` as it will dispatch to the already existing `[[<-.myClass` method.

In similar S3 dispatching cases, I've been able use `UseMethod` or specifically call  `[[<-.list`, or `[[<-.default` but those don't seem to exist because `$<-` and `[[<-` are primitive generics, right?  And I'm sure I'll be sent to a special R hell if I try to call `.Primitive("$<-")`.  What is the correct way to dispatch the assignment to the default assignment method?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? `$<-` is not the same as `[[<-`.

Comment: Have you tried using `NextMethod()`? That would be the obvious place to start.

Comment: Except that $ does non-standard evaluation, so this is going to be hard

Comment: I have tried NextMethod, but maybe I wasn't calling it correctly? Current solution is to remove the class from x, call [[x]]<-value, and re-add the class. But this is expensive because it causes three copies of X to be made.  Seems like it should be possible to tell NextMethod to dispatch to 'no class at all' but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there is a particularly elegant way to do this. The `data.frame` method for `$<-` looks like this:

```
`$<-.data.frame` <- function (x, name, value) {
  cl <- oldClass(x)
  class(x) <- NULL
  x[[name]] <- value
  class(x) <- cl
  x
}
```

(with error checking code omitted)

This should only create one copy of x, because `class<-` modifies in place, and so does the default method for `[[<-`.

Comment: > myFrame<-data.frame()
> myFrame<-data.frame(a="a")
> tracemem(myFrame)
[1] "<0xb3889e8>"
myFrame[['a']]<-1
tracemem[0xb21a8e8 -> 0xaf37df0]: 
tracemem[0xaf37df0 -> 0xaf38110]: [[<-.data.frame [[<- 
tracemem[0xaf38110 -> 0xaf38490]: [[<-.data.frame [[<-
Doesn't this mean multiple copies are made?

Comment: @skyebend, When you set the `class` to `NULL`, `x` will remain a NAMED list, and `[[<-` will create a copy. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424626/why-is-preallocation-useful-for-list for some examples of when copying on lists might be taking place.