# What happens when I append a new element to a list (which is internally a vector)?

Tags: r

It seems R internally implements lists as vectors.  "Lists are VECSXP [...]" -- [R internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#R-Internal-Structures).

That is, lists are generic vectors.

Generic vectors must be vectors containing pointers to their elements instead of storing the elements themselves in the vector position.  This creates a vector that can store any element in it, hence the term "generic".  (Assuming this proceeds, ...)

So lists can be represented by generic vectors.  What happens when I want to append a new element to a list (which is internally a vector) whose internal vector doesn't have any more space for a new element?  Is the vector reallocated?

Related question: [Why does is.vector() return TRUE for list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032772)

Comment: Maybe related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129466 (and if the question transforms into one of performance, maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046336/here-we-go-again-append-an-element-to-a-list-in-r)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the internal implementation of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129068/what-is-the-internal-implementation-of-lists)